# Geometric interpretation of Leibniz formula for $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, euclidean-geometry, circles, pi

We know $\pi=4(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}....)$. I'm wondering, is there a geometric interpretation of this identity. Can we prove this identity by finding a different way to determine the area of the unit circle for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the derivation uses the quarter of a unit circle.

See [Leibniz's Proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz's_Formula_for_Pi#Leibniz.27s_Proof).